# How to change wordpress core files without changing the core files?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am a developer who has recently come across a problem I'm sure can be resolved but I can't figure out how exactly. I want to add styles and `div` to wordpress core files but obviously that is bad practice, so how do I do it?

For example: I would like to add

```
<div class="my_class"><?php code here ?></div>
```

and i would like it to go at the top of my admin menu (the menu on the right)

I have found a few different articles and from that i can add menu items etc., but not custom html code. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to change the templates.

Since you wisely don't want to change WordPress's core code itself, what you'll want to do instead is make a new theme (which can just be a copy of WordPress's default theme, or a child theme), and customize your custom theme.

You'll want to look at [Theme Development](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) and [Child Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) in the WordPress documentation for further guidance.